# Problem getting useState to function when UseEffect is called

Tags: reactjs

I cant get the state to be updated when useEffect is called. Currently trying to retrieve posts from my backend server running locally. I am able to get the array when console logging data but after calling setPosts(data), all I get is an empty array when console logging Posts. Tried running retrievePosts with a button and it works fine but I'm trying to get the posts for rendering whenever the page is refreshed.

```
function App() {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    async function retrievePosts() {
        const {data} = await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000");
        console.log(data)
        setPosts(data);
        console.log(posts);
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        retrievePosts();
    },[]);

    return (
    <Router>
        <Navibar/>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path = "/" element = {<Home retrievePosts = {retrievePosts}/>}/>
            <Route exact path = "/compose" element = {<Compose/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this problem because `useState` works asynchronous. When you invoke `console.log(posts)` after `setPosts(data)` your `posts` in state is not actually contain `data`.

To work with it you should, for example, and another `useEffect` and pass to it as dependency `posts` and log to console there:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(posts); // you can do anything what you want here when you've got posts
}, [posts])
```

Answer (score 0):

setPosts() doesn’t update the state immediately instead schedules the state update. I think state should get updated correctly but you are consoling "post" at wrong place. Try outputting it just before return statement.